# Is the serial device connected well?

Tags: usb, serial

I'm using rapberry 3 B+.

and Connect to a serial to usb device.

The following is dmesg after connection.

```
[ 5021.125504] usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otg
[ 5021.272788] usb 1-1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=0483, idProduct=5740, bcdDevice= 2.00
[ 5021.272805] usb 1-1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 5021.272817] usb 1-1.2: Product: SiCa2301D2129000103
[ 5021.272829] usb 1-1.2: Manufacturer: STMicroelectronics
[ 5021.272841] usb 1-1.2: SerialNumber: 207C34663156
[ 5021.336911] cdc_acm 1-1.2:1.0: ttyACM0: USB ACM device
[ 5021.339173] usbcore: registered new interface driver cdc_acm
[ 5021.339183] cdc_acm: USB Abstract Control Model driver for USB modems and ISDN adapters
```

Can I check the tnt data with cat /dev/ttyACM0 command in this situation?

Or should I check other settings?

For now, there is no output.

Comment: you have a serial to USB device plugged into a USB port of your pi ... what's connected to the serial part of the serial to USB device?

Comment: I connected the gas sensor. However, the serial port of this sensor is for interworking with Windows-based serial programs. I tried to check if any serial data is coming out of this port.